# Run Azure Function Service Bus Trigger in Docker Container locally and K8S

Tags: docker, azure-functions

This may be a simple thing but I'm struggling to get my head around how to run a Service Bus trigger (or any background task trigger) under Azure Functions 3.0, in a docker container, in order to run locally (for testing) and eventually in K8S.

Most of the examples I've found (including from MS) appear to use the simple HTTP Trigger. Although I'm using a compiled C# function, I found one python example that was for Service Bus, but it's very unclear how you actually **run** the function once in the container locally for testing or in a none AKS environment. The examples I've found don't reference this step - it appears to be 'magic'.

I've used func init --docker-only --csharp to patch together this docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet:3.0

COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/bin/ /home/site/wwwroot
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot
```

but what this doesn't tell  me is how I need to start the azure function. The azure functions base docker image doesn't contain the func tools so that I can call func xxxxxx in my dockerfile to start the function.

I'm expecting something like an ENTRYPOINT that I'd use for a normal web api or some other step to invoke a BASH command to start the azure function but the default dockerfile created by 'func' doesn't include this.

I don't think it matters but eventually we are going to run these on a local K8S deployment for development testing - they may never actually run in AKS itself.

Comment: In the end it is magic as it is working. The key is to add 

ENV AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

to the docker file. This then writes out the logging that the host it executing and you can then see the functions being started.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to get it to work as well but the one thing that give the most problems for me is the connection strings.
These are given via the environment variables.

For service bus look really into when to use the string of the namespace and when to use the one of the queue/topic.

If you want to look more into some documentation of azure function in k8s look into the package KEDA.

Comment: In the end, we gave up as they do not work that well in docker containers unless you are prepared to pass the connection string as a single value. In our case, we want to pass a template connection string to the container and then pull the security credentials from a key vault to update the template at run time. The Azure Function framework for Service Bus doesn't work that way - it expects the connection string to be complete on container start up.

In the end we re-wrote the it as a hosted service. it was much easier to configure and we didn't really lose that much over azure functions

Comment: We are now trying it out and will use the key vault connection to deal with it. Hosted service is an option of your service can run all the time, was that the case or did you make it scale in a different way?

Comment: We went with hosted service in the end. We had to add the additional code to hook up to service bus ourselves but, frankly, this made a lot of other configuration problems go away too as we had total control. Looking back, I really don't think Azure Functions in containers is worth the trouble - running a simple service in a pod lets us do what we want without having to fight the Functions framework, and we have the advantages of KEDA anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you are passing the following as environment variables:

- "ServiceBusConnection" (ConnectionString) or "ServiceBusConnection__fullyQualifiedNamespace" if you are using managed Identities.
- "AzureWebJobsStorage" or "AzureWebJobsStorage__accountName" if you are using managed Identities.

Documentation for using identity-based connections instead of secrets with triggers and bindings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-identity-based-connections-tutorial-2

Answer (score 0):

Another issue that I have found recently was that because I had the following NuGet Package installed in the Azure Functions project, the functions would never get triggered and also no output of any errors would show up in the Logs.
After I removed the package and the call in Startup, everything started working properly.

Do not add this package:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Kubernetes
```

Comment: Why does this prevent startup of the Functions?